# Getting the top and left (x, y) coordinates of a minimized Chrome window (JS)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I don't think this can be done in a very simple or clean way if at all, but I'm all out of ideas for this so I'll take anything I can.

In Firefox and IE, a window's top and left variables can be read whether the window is minimized or maximized. In Chrome, when the window is minimized, both of those variables will become '-32000'.

Is there any way to get the actual coordinates of the window before it closes? I tried adding an alert function into an onbeforeunload listener, but alert calls can't be made from inside that listener.

Comment: What higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: `beforeunload` is not the same thing as minimizing. You can place code in the `resize` event and test the size to see if it is `<= 0`.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to save a Chrome windows coordinates if it was closed while minimized.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to detect when the browser window has been minimized, and screenX/screenY is the only way to get the coordinates, but as you discovered Chrome sets them to something else when minimized. (Which ironically kind of gives you a way to know that it's minimized.)

The only option I can think of is polling the window coordinates every so often and saving them in a variable/localStorage/etc. You can check for -32000 and ignore it, which will leave you with the last valid coordinates before minimizing.